# Will apt-get download the same version of a package manually added to /var/cache/apt/archives?

Tags: apt, package-management

Imagine, I have all packages to install, say, `ddd`.
If I copy all `ddd` packages to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and run `sudo apt-get install ddd` in terminal, will `apt-get` re-download the packages or skip them?

**PS** I currently have `ddd` installed, so I can't (won't) test it myself. So I need some expert to tell me what would happen :)

Comment: i didn't find any `/var/apt/cache`.

Comment: which type of packages you had .deb or tar.gz?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it will, but only if the package is part of any lists that where downloaded while doing a `apt-get update`, eg:

- You get a package that comes from a PPA that you want to use and you add the package manually to `/var/cache/apt/archives`, because the version of the package is not present on any package list from your sources it will not be used.

Packages are also signed, so if the signature from the package does not match the expected signature then it will be downloaded again, package identification does not depend on the name of the file only.

Making it short: if the manually added package version and signature match anything in your sources package list then that package will be used, else it will be downloaded again.

Answer (score 5):

No , It would not download it again. Here I am installing a previously uninstalled package which is present in my `/var/cache/apt/archives` directory.

`sudo apt-get install artha`

[image]

Comment: This is not conclusive unless you manually copied the file there and there was no earlier presence of artha on the system.

Comment: As I assume uninstalling a package also means the same .

Comment: You assume there is no mention anywhere else?
But I have verified this by manually getting a package from Ubuntu and adding it to the cache before install.
So now for sure, it will not download the file again.

Comment: @guruprasad I would select your answer as accepted, but Bruno Pereira's answer is more detailed. Anyway thanks, and +1 for great answer and a great wallpaper :)